# How do I access the results of a JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json

How can I loop through the JSON results from this C# Rest API call:

```
        string url = string.Format("https://example.com/api/mytext");
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.UserAgent = "mykey";
        req.Accept = "text/json";

        using (System.Net.HttpWebResponse resp = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            if (resp.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                // how do I access the JSON here and loop through it?

            }
        }
```

There is no "data" in the resp object:

[image: Showing resp object]

Visual Studio doesn't seem to show any results in "resp" - but I know they are there, as I've seen results in postman.

Thanks, Mark

Comment: isn't it in resp.Data?

Comment: Hi - no, there's no data in resp (I'll add a screeshot in my post) - thanks.

Comment: JSON is just a string. Yoou need to *read* the response to get that string. You'd have to get the response stream with `GetResponseStream()` and read it with a StreamReader. It's a lot easier and more scaleable to use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [GetStringAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GetResponseStream()` with a `StreamReader`

```
string url = string.Format("https://example.com/api/mytext");
System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "GET";
req.UserAgent = "mykey";
req.Accept = "text/json";

using (System.Net.HttpWebResponse resp = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    if (resp.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        string contents;
        // how do I access the JSON here and loop through it?
        using(var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        using(var responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            contents = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var deserializedContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(contents);
    }
}
```

See more on [GetResponseStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_HttpWebResponse_GetResponseStream)

See more on [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.7.2)

See more on [JsonConvert](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm)

Dependencies: [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 2):

Use [HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_HttpWebResponse_GetResponseStream) method to get the result as a `Stream`. Then you can use [Newtonsoft JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to parse the result.

```
using (System.Net.HttpWebResponse resp = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
        if (resp.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Process data with JSON.NET library here
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response);